# E: Unable to locate package ros-galactic-ros-gz

Tags: ros-galactic, gazebo-edifice, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install (ignition) Gazebo Edifice on my Ubuntu 20.04 system which already has ROS2 Galactic installed on it.

I'm using the command `sudo apt-get install ros-galactic-ros-gz` as mentioned [here](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/ros_installation#installing-gazebo-with-older-versions-of-ros). But `apt` says it's not able to find the binaries as shown below.
[image]

How should I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Please use text instead of sharing a screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found on galactic branch of the [ros_gz github repo](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/galactic) that I've to install using `sudo apt install ros-galactic-ros-ign`

Answer (score 0):

Before running `sudo apt install ros-galactic-ros-gz` command, you need to add `ROS 2 apt repositories` to your system's sources list as given [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz).

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list'
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I was getting the same error even after adding "ROS 2 apt repositories to my system's sources list". Later, I found on `galactic` branch of the https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz repo that I've to install using `sudo apt install ros-galactic-ros-ign`